# Kafka data reads and offset management with sink

Tags: apache-kafka

What happens when the consumer reads the data from `kafka` but fails to write into `sink`. Lets say, I read the data from `kafka` and applied some transformation on data and finally storing the final result into Database. If everything is perfectly working my final result will be stored in Database. But lets say for some reason my Database isn't available. what happens with the data that i read from `kafka`? When I restart my application, can I read the same data again since I failed to store it in sink? or will the `kafka` marks this data as read and will not allow me to read this data?

can you also tell me what this property is used for - `enable.auto.commit=true`?

Comment: I do have similar scenario, if someone can explain, if my foreach writer fails, how the checkpoint will behave in this case and how to configure Kafka offset commit after my sink has written the data into database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a part of the metadata in Kafka called *consumer offsets*. Each message has a unique offset - an integer value that continually increases for each message.

So, in the scenario you've described:

If, you've committed the offset ***BEFORE*** writing to the database then you will not be able to read those messages again.

But, if you commit the offset ***AFTER*** writing to the database then you will be able to re-read those messages.

`enable.auto.commit=true` as the name suggests will automatically commit consumer offsets after a certain time interval defined by `auto.commit.interval.ms` parameter - which by default is 5000 ms (5 seconds). So, as you can probably imagine that if these default values are used, then the offsets will be committed in 5 seconds regardless of whether they have landed in the destination or not.

So, you would basically need to control these through your code and change the `enable.auto.commit` to `false` if you'd like to ensure guaranteed delivery.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you shade some more light on how to manually configure kafka offset commit ensuring it is done after writing the data into database

Comment: @agaonsindhe - Well, I would suggest to look for such examples in the public domain. The first reference I would recommend is the Kafka definitive guide as that contains some relevant examples along with the explanation. If you still run into issues, then please feel free to post another comment here or a new question and I'll surely help you out.

Comment: Turns out spark is not committing anything if writer sink(JDBC in my case) fail,the checkpoint is working as expected and I m seeing no message getting lost if sink fails. Thank u so much for the assistance.

Comment: @agaonsindhe - I'm glad it worked out for you. :)